# Why is DependencyProperty null after binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, initialization, dependency-properties

After I bind `ReportSettings` to `SettingsProperty` I would expect to be able to access `ReportSettings` through the `Settings` property. When I try to do so I get an `NullReferenceException`.
Can anyone help me out here?

`ReportSettings` is a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public MyWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    // Load default template
    string defaultTemplateName = "default";
    foreach (var reportSettings in SettingsCache.Instance.AllReportSettings) {
        if (reportSettings.TemplateName.Equals(defaultTemplateName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            var binding = new Binding("SettingsProperty") { Source = reportSettings };
            SetBinding(SettingsProperty, binding);
            var testDirect = reportSettings.IsVisible; // OK
            var testDepProp = Settings.IsVisible; // NullReferenceException!!!
            //...
        }
    }
}

public ReportSettings Settings {
    get { return (ReportSettings)GetValue(SettingsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SettingsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SettingsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Settings", typeof(ReportSettings), typeof(MyWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSettingsChanged));
```

Update:
In this example I can just use the local variable, but the example is just for easy illustration of the problem. The problem really occurs after construction, where I access the uninitialized 'Settings'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine helped me out. It was simply a basic error in the binding. This fixed the issue:

`var binding = new Binding() { Source = reportSettings };`

Answer (score 2):

It's because data binding is executed asynchronously on a lower priority thread. So after you hook up the binding, your code will continue executing before the binding actually gets to update the value, hence it still being `null`.

You can either just use the local `reportSettings` value (as you discovered), or use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` to execute your follow-up code, using a `DispatcherPriority` lower than `DispatcherPriority.DataBind`.

Comment: I would have voted you up if I could - since you pointed out and suggested a solution for another issue in the code...